# ¿Cómo dividir una cadena por otra cadena usando Split en VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, split

Estoy intentando dividir una cadena similar a esta:

```cs
"<span>1</span> - Selección"
```

Y obtener el valor que está encerrado entre los `<span>`.

Mediante `JavaScript` lo que hago es esto:

```js
var ejemplo = "<span>1</span> - Selección";

var separacion = ejemplo.replace("</span>","<span>").split("<span>");
console.log("Split: ",separacion);
//Da como resultado ["","1"," - Selección"]
console.log("Valor que necesito obtener: ",separacion[1]); //tomo el valor que necesito
```

Y listo, eso tal cual necesito hacer pero en Visual .NET, pero no me funciona.

Intente:

```vb
Dim CadenaString As String = "<span>1</span> - Selección"
Dim idSeleccion As String() = CadenaString.Replace("</span>","<span>").Split("<span>")
```

o enviando ya todos los `</span>` reemplazados en la cadena para solo hacer

```vb
Dim CadenaString As String = "<span>1<span> - Selección"
Dim idSeleccion As String() = CadenaString.Split("<span>")
```

Pero me deja en la posición (1) `"span>1"` siempre, y no me hace el split como en `JS`

**¿Cómo lo puedo hacer correctamente?**

---

Para simular el código `VB.Net` usen https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Peguen este código:

```vb
Imports System

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim CadenaString As String = "<span>1</span> - Selection"
        Dim idSelection As String() = CadenaString.Replace("</span>","<span>").Split("<span>")
        Console.WriteLine(idSelection(1))
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Fabian, si mi respuesta no funciono, o la modificamos o pones una respuesta que si funcione. Agregar una respuesta en ingles en tu pregunta no es correcto. Y menos, en ingles!. Ahora, eso es lo mismo que escribi yo en mi respuesta. si la parte que no funciono es la de las opciones, se puede aclarar. Pero asi como la editaste, es mas confuso todavia. voy a revertir tu edicion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función [split](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_String___System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_) tiene varias formas de ser usada.

El tema, es que por como la escribiste, esta usando esta version:

```
Public Function Split (ParamArray separator As Char()) As String()
```

Porque las versiones que usan un string, que es lo que vos necesitas, necesita un array de strings como separador.

Entonces, la solucion es pasarla un array de strings. para eso, agregamos el separador como un array de strings:

```
Dim stringSeparators() As String = {"<span>"}
```

Y luego, en el split, hacemos lo siguiente:

```
Dim idSelection As String() = CadenaString.Replace("</span>","<span>").Split(stringSeparators,StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Usamos esta versión de split:

```
Public Function Split (separator As String(), options As StringSplitOptions) As String()
```

De esa forma, obtenes el valor que queres.

Comment: La que me funcionó fue `Dim idSelection As String() = WordString.Replace("</span>","<span>").Split({"<span>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`